# Error when trying to run .jar file with javamail due to messagingException

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm writing a little automated response program for my SO, and have incorporated an email function into it as a gimmick/test for myself. I have got the source code running fine in netbeans but when I try to run the .jar itself in the Mac terminal i get Error: Unable to initialize main class [class name]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
I am fairly new to java so I apologise for any vagueness or simplicity in the problem, but if there's anything that needs clarifying ill try my best

I've tried just regularly running the .jar by double clicking and running it in terminal and neither works, but when i build and run the source code in netbeans, the program runs fine. I suspect it may to do with the catching exception line but I don't really know why.

```
try{
                    //sets variables to store custom subject and body data
                    System.out.print("Subject: ");
                    //input is name of scanner
                    String subject=input.next();
                    System.out.print("Body: ");
                    String body=input.next();                               

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    //sets sender as my email
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myemail@gmail.com"));
                    //sets recipient as other email
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("recipientemail@msn.com"));
                    //sets subject and content as variables defined earlier
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
                    //sends message
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");
            //catches and throws a necessary messaging exception
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: I think problem with running jar file from command line is that you don't have java.mail in your classpath, but when you run from IDE, it is added to project as external library.

Comment: Okay so would I do that through a dependency or is there some other way of doing it?

Comment: You can add mail jar to classpath to execute your jar. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: that's a lot for my little brain to get around but after doing some reading I have recognised that this would be the solution. Once I figure out how to set classpaths and stuff I'm assuming it'll work fine but for now I'll mark your answer as correct. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with running jar file from command line is that you don't have java.mail in your classpath, but when you run from IDE, it is added to project as external library. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html
from @user999